# Simply Getting instance of a class with "__init__(self)" method in Python

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm new to python and I can't get instance of the class below Which is in a python file named "util.py":

```
...
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
...
```

And I'm trying to construct an instance of the aforementioned class in another python file named "Search.py";Here's the code :

```
def depthFirstSearch(problem):

   from util import Stack

   path = [] #list used to return the desired actions

   DFSstack = Stack()
```

There's really nothing more in my code believe me!:)
But I get this error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Help me out please!

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback as well; there is *nothing* in this code that'll throw that exception.

Comment: You are not iterating over anything, for starters.

Comment: Let me review my code

Comment: @MartijnPieters You were right, the problem wasn't because of constructing an instance; Turned out that it was because of a wrong list definition somewhere else in another related .py file.Anyway Thanks a lot for your goodness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `__init__` directly; call the *class*:

```
>>> class Stack:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.list = []
... 
>>> DFSstack = Stack()
```

The `__init__` initializer method will then be called automatically.

Comment: I tried that either but i got this error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @MortezaFarhang: Not with the code you posted.

Comment: Is there any way I can get instance of the class by calling "__init__()"??!

Comment: @MortezaFarhang: Calling the unbound `Stack.__init__()` method is *certainly* wrong as no instance is created. If you get a `TypeError` *elsewhere* then that is a completely new problem, unrelated to your question.

Comment: @MortezaFarhang: Why are you trying to create an instance by calling the initializer? `__init__` is called *after* the instance is constructed. Call `Stack.__new__()` if you want to bypass that; `__new__` is the constructor.

Comment: @MortezaFarhang: Note that only new-style classes have a `__new__` function; I am assuming here that this is Python 3. In Python 2, inherit from `object` to make your class new-style.

Comment: I'm on python 2, so "__new__" won't work for me I guess.Besides I'm still not able to construct the instance,As you suggested I 'm gonna check other parts of the code and maybe get to find out why am I getting "TypeError"

Comment: @SteveJessop I tried that And as I told I'm getting this error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Perhaps you want to tell us what you are trying to do? And include your full code that throws that error; edit your question to add information.

Comment: @MortezaFarhang: *What code* throws that exception? Not the class you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let Stack inherit from list? It almost works the same as a list, but you can add your own methods to it.

```
class Stack(list):
    pass
```

Comment: You'r right I guess , But I'm doing a Computer Assignment in college and we're kindda not supposed to change the Stack definition structure:)